# Trying to get VBA to handle event of any form showing

Tags: vba, excel, userform

So I'm trying to get an event to kick off any time any userform is shown in a workbook. They'll all be doing the same thing, but I don't want to have to code the same activity for each `UserFormX.Show`.

I've read about `UserForm_Activate()` and `UserForm_Initialize()` and understand they are something like the following.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ''Do some stuff
End Sub
```

I also understand that `UserForm` should be the name of the form itself. Is there any way for this to happen with ANY userform that is activated/shown?

Thanks

Comment: if theyre doing the same thing why do you need multiple userforms?

Comment: you can try [this](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/handle_multiple_userform_buttons_with_one_subroutine/) technique but change commandbuttons to userforms, but i have never tested this on userforms

Comment: @scott They are for different things, but I want them in the same location, or moved to a certain place on screen. That kind of stuff that I would normally have to manipulate the properties of each form, or add code to when each form is initialized. That is what I meant by the same. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you are after, but it may be the closest you can get.

Add a reference to `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library`

In a standard module create a `Sub` to handle to common actions

```
Sub FormInitialize(frm As MSForms.UserForm)
    With frm

        ' do stuff

    End With
End Sub
```

In each form module create a standard `Initialize event`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    FormInitialize Me
End Sub
```

Still have to create a `Sub` for each form, but at least its always the same, and there is only one copy of the actual initialise logic.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call a routine in your mainline code from each form's Initialize event?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Call MainCode_FormHandler(.Me)
End Sub
```

and in the main code:

```
Public Sub MainCode_FormHandler(oForm as Form)
   With oForm
      ' Set form's properties here
   End With
End With
```

You could include logic that tests oForm.Tag if you need to identify which form has been passed.  Set the form's tag in the form's Properties dialog.